# benchmarking python script reveals mysterious time delays

Tags: python, time, benchmarking

i have two modules: moduleParent and moduleChild

i'm doing something like this in moduleParent:

```
import moduleChild

#a bunch of code

start = time.time()
moduleChild.childFunction()
finish = time.time()
print "calling child function takes:", finish-start, "total seconds"

#a bunch of code
```

i'm doing something like this in moduleChild:

```
def childFunction():
    start = time.time()
    #a bunch of code
    finish = time.time()
    print "child function says it takes:", finish-start, "total seconds"
```

the output looks like this:

```
calling child function takes: .24 total seconds
child function says it takes: 0.0 total seconds
```

so my question is, where are these .24 extra seconds coming from?

thank you for your expertise.

#

here is the actual code for "childFuntion". it really shouldn't take .24 seconds.

```
 def getResources(show, resourceName='', resourceType=''):
   '''
   get a list of resources with the given name

   @show: show name
   @resourceName: name of resource
   @resourceType: type of resource
   @return: list of resource dictionaries
   '''

   t1 = time.time()

   cmd = r'C:\tester.exe -cmdFile "C:\%s\info.txt" -user root -pwd root'%show
   cmd += " -cmd findResources -machineFormatted "

   if resourceName:
       cmd += '-name %s'%resourceName

   if resourceType:
       cmd += '_' + resourceType.replace(".", "_") + "_"

   proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   output = proc.stdout.read()
   output = output.strip()

   resourceData = output.split("\r\n")
   resourceData = resourceData[1:]

   resourceList = []
   for data in resourceData:
       resourceId, resourceName, resourceType = data.split("|")
       rTyp = "_" + resourceType.replace(".", "_") + "_"
       shot, assetName = resourceName.split(rTyp)
       resourceName = assetName
       path = '//projects/%s/scenes/%s/%s/%s'%(show, shot, resourceType.replace(".", "/"), assetName)
       resourceDict = {'id':resourceId, 'name':resourceName, 'type':resourceType, 'path':path }
       resourceList.append(resourceDict)

   t2 = time.time()
   print ("     ", t2 - t2, "seconds")


   return resourceList
```

Comment: Is that the exact output? Aren't the lines reversed?

Comment: it is not the exact output, no. this is just a simplified example.

Comment: You have your answer `t2 - t2` = 0

Comment: oh my god. i am an imbecile. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2: I just noticed a typo in child function, you have  t2 - t2 in the print statement

ignore below:

<strike>Calling the function itself has overhead (setting up stack space, saving local variables, returning, etc). The result suggests that your function is so trivial that setting up for a function call took longer than running the code itself.</strike>

Edit: also, calling the timers as well as print ads overhead. Now that I think about it, calling print could account for a lot of that .24 seconds. IO is slow.

Comment: What does childFunction do? It's hard to imagine the overhead of a function call that takes .24 seconds on any reasonable system, certainly for a function that can be completed in 0.0 seconds.  I guess maybe you could be deleting the last reference that frees up an enormous amount of objects for the garbage collector.

Comment: Not to mention the time it took the child to print how long it took, which isn't included in the time it says it took. :-)

Comment: @MRAB, yes but a print statement shouldn't take .24 sec!

Comment: see my latest edit, you have a typo in the child function's print statement, t2 - t2 should be t2 - t1

Answer (score 0):

You can't measure the time of a function by running it once, especially one which runs so short. There are a myriad of factors which could affect the timing, not the least of which is what other processes you have running on the system.

Something like this I would probably run at least a few hundred times. Check out the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.